# How to display two row listView in a tab?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-tabhost

I want to display a two row listview filled with data from the database but how can i set the list item to display?

Comment: Do you mean ListView with item which contains 2 rows?

Comment: yeah i have retreived the data but i dont know how to set it on the tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should understand the concept of [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). When list item appears on the screen, [getView(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) is called to provide data to the item. There you can provide data to your 'rows'.
To create your list item you should supply xml layout file  containing two views. 
Take a look at [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). You should slightly modify it to solve the problem.

Comment: Mighter it worked for me!!! ive got all the database things right but im new on tabs soo i guess there are bit of differences still learning it...Thanx  alot mate :) BACK ON TRACK